# Real World Deployment With Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to understand the complexities of deploying Rails in a real server, to handle real daily traffic. Think of a 2GHz server with 2GB Ram, running Apache along with Passenger.

I would like to ask you what are some nice and professional resources on deploying a Rails app. How would one go about creating a versatile deployment configuration, what should one be cautious about, how to handle possible problems on scaling and such. For instance, i'm hearing that Capistrano is pretty much used in real deployment.

When things are getting serious, everything needs to work fine and development code should quickly match the production code, what are the best practices that professionals follow ?

Comment: Capistrano is definitely the way to proceed: easy, configurable, professional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexities come with the add-ons to Rails that you use. Search indexing, background jobs, logging -- these add complexity.

In a standard Rails+SQL deployment, using Capistrano is incredibly simple and robust. Each deployment will create a folder in /u/apps/your-app-name/versions and will symlink to /u/apps/your-app-name/current ... If you point passenger/apache to that folder, you're 90% of the way there.